# Element <a> not clickable when using routerLink directive

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I have `<a routerLink="login">login</a>`, but it is rendered as plain text, just like if I used `<span>login</span>`.

I'm certain, that there is no mistake in my routing, since if I added a button `<button (click)="onClick()">navigate</button>` and the handler, `constructor(private router: Router) {} onClick() { this.router.navigate(['/login']); }` this works perfectly.

Any suggestions why i can't navigate with `routerLink`?

Comment: Try [routerLink] instead of routerlink.

Comment: Are there any errors on the browser console when you click on the link?

Comment: I tried [routerLink], but i get an error: NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. There are no errors on the console, because the link isn't even clickable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the `RouterModule` in you `AppModule`